# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.jasper.compiler.EncodingDetector

Tags: java, centos6, tomcat8.5

I have installed tomcat 8.5.37 on Centos server and opening server at 8081 port I am getting error as

```
 `Message java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.jasper.compiler.EncodingDetector

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.jasper.compiler.EncodingDetector
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Root Cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.jasper.compiler.EncodingDetector
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.determineSyntaxAndEncoding(ParserController.java:323)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:200)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parseDirectives(ParserController.java:127)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:197)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:373)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:350)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:334)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:595)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:399)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

and

```
Exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:197)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:413)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Root Cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:129)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:60)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:192)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:413)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

I have provided tomcat permissions and checked installation all seems fine.
I am new to Centos so not sure where its going wrong

Comment: There are some changes related to JSP rendering in 8.5.*.Temporary fix would be go back to previous jasper jar version OR change all JSPs with broken tags.